# GDP projections for the fifty American states

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, data-request

I'm looking for GDP projections for the fifty American states (up till 2040, or 2050). Are these available online, or in any economics papers?

I've found GDP projections for America, and historical GDP data for the fifty states. While GDP projections are not reliable, I need this for a project that I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Official forecasts seem not to be available. The Bureau of Economic Analysis did produce these forecast in the past, but [not anymore](https://www.bea.gov/faq/index.cfm?faq_id=456).

Forecasts from academic economists are scarce. US studies are usually only available for **employment** and not for GDP (for example, [this paper](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeeintfor/v_3a28_3ay_3a2012_3ai_3a2_3ap_3a315-327.htm)). A [working paper](http://econpapers.repec.org/paper/cesceswps/_5f5145.htm) from late 2014 reviews the literature on regional forecasting (not only for the US) and the state-of-the-art methodology of such exercises. You can see in Table 1 a summary of studies between 1975 and 2015. None of them focuses on GDP for US states. Notice however that there are such studies for Germany ([Wenzel, 2013](https://ideas.repec.org/p/zbw/hwwirp/133.html)) and Europe ([Baltagi et. al. 2014](https://ideas.repec.org/a/bla/obuest/v76y2014i1p112-138.html)), so maybe in the future an equivalent for the US will be produced.